# Symfony 1.4 set default application for command line tasks

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, command-line-interface

I'm looking for a solution for the following problem:

In a symfony 1.4 project, I have 2 applications: `frontend` and `backend`.
Whenever I run a symfony cli task like `php symfony doctrine:build --all-classes`, symfony uses
the `backend` application as default.

How do I make symfony cli use `frontend` as the default application?

I know i can run the same command as `php symfony --application=frontend doctrine:build --all-classes` but there must be a way to make it use the `frontend` app as default.

**Edit:**

Found this method in `lib/vendor/symfony/lib/task/sfBaseTask.class.php`

```
/**
 * Returns the first application in apps.
 *
 * @return string The Application name
 */
protected function getFirstApplication()
{
    if (count($dirs = sfFinder::type('dir')->maxdepth(0)->follow_link()->relative()->in(sfConfig::get('sf_apps_dir'))))
    {
        return $dirs[0];
    }

   return null;
}
```

Seems the order is alphabetical ...

Thanks.

Comment: Is backend the first application you create ? (ie: before frontend)

Comment: no, first i created frontend, then backend

Comment: But why do you want to choose which application run `doctrine:build` since this task generate doctrine class for the whole project?

Comment: One application `(frontend)` is using Apostrophe, which adds some code needed to build the classes, while `backend` does not include Apostrophe.

Answer (score 1):

Check in `configure` method of your task, you should see something like that :

```php
new sfCommandOption('application', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_REQUIRED, 'The application name', 'backend'),
```

Replace `backend` by `frontend`.

**Edit:**

According to what you find (about the `getFirstApplication`), the best solution is to create your own task (in `/lib/task/myDoctrineBuildTask.class.php`) that extends the current doctrine task. Then define the `frontend` application in the `configure` method:

```php
class myDoctrineBuildTask extends sfDoctrineBuildTask
{
  /**
   * @see sfTask
   */
  protected function configure()
  {
    $this->addOptions(array(
      new sfCommandOption('application', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_OPTIONAL, 'The application name', 'frontend'),
      new sfCommandOption('env', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_REQUIRED, 'The environment', 'dev'),
      new sfCommandOption('no-confirmation', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_NONE, 'Whether to force dropping of the database'),
      new sfCommandOption('all', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_NONE, 'Build everything and reset the database'),
      new sfCommandOption('all-classes', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_NONE, 'Build all classes'),
      new sfCommandOption('model', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_NONE, 'Build model classes'),
      new sfCommandOption('forms', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_NONE, 'Build form classes'),
      new sfCommandOption('filters', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_NONE, 'Build filter classes'),
      new sfCommandOption('sql', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_NONE, 'Build SQL'),
      new sfCommandOption('db', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_NONE, 'Drop, create, and either insert SQL or migrate the database'),
      new sfCommandOption('and-migrate', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_NONE, 'Migrate the database'),
      new sfCommandOption('and-load', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_OPTIONAL | sfCommandOption::IS_ARRAY, 'Load fixture data'),
      new sfCommandOption('and-append', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_OPTIONAL | sfCommandOption::IS_ARRAY, 'Append fixture data'),
    ));

    $this->namespace = 'mydoctrine';
    $this->name = 'build';

    $this->briefDescription = 'Generate code based on your schema';

    $this->detailedDescription = ''; // feel free to re-add all the doc
  }
}
```

And then, launch the build using: `php symfony mydoctrine:build --all-classes`

Comment: It's not a custom task and I don't want to change the symfony/doctrine source.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't know it was related to a core task.

Comment: I want to avoid doing that as someone might invoke the core task instead

Answer (score 0):

When you run the `cache:clear` tasks without a specific application, Symfony clears the cache for ALL applications. This can be observed in the [source of this task](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/task/cache/sfCacheClearTask.class.php#L84). For tasks (that you created yourself) that do provide a default application, you can simply change it to whatever you want.

Comment: ok maybe the `cache:clear` command was not a good example, the issue i'm having is with the doctrine:build command

Answer (score 0):

This is four years too late, and hopefully Symfony 1.x is not used too much these days, but the file system determines what is the default application. The application queries applications directory, and the first folder is used as the default application. So you can hack your way around it by modifying the file system, but it is strongly not recommended to do so.